# how to use CGRectIntersectsRect to load a storyboard(using cocos2d and Tiled)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

my school group is creating an application in Xcode for iPhone 7.0 sdk. we already have the Tile map created, loaded, running. NPCs are loaded and appear on screen. we already have movement around the map. i have figured out how to create a CGRect around both the player and one NPC, but need ideas/ways to load a storyboard containing dialog. here is what we have:

```
CGRect sherpaRect;
sherpaRect.origin = CGPointMake(397,1908);
sherpaRect.size.width = 20;
sherpaRect.size.height = 20;

CGRect playerRect;
playerRect.origin = playerPos;
playerRect.size.width = 20;
playerRect.size.height = 20;

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sherpaRect, playerRect)) {
//code needed to load storyboard

//added after question was initially asked
UIStoryboard *MainStoryboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

EditorViewController *editorVC=[MainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myEditor"];

[self presentViewController:editorVC animated:YES completion:nil];
//end added section
}
```

the collision works as putting a breakpoint at the commented out section (//code needed to load storyboard) successfully stops the program.

we are simply looking for how to load a storyboard at this point(and if any return actions might be needed upon exiting the storyboard and going back to the game map)

***new code causes an issue: "instance method presentViewController:animated:completion not found(return type default to 'id')"

Comment: Define what a storyboard is to you because I get the feeling you don't mean an iOS storyboard (i.e. user interface file). Are you trying to display text to the cocos2d screen? It wouldn't make sense to load a iOS storyboard in a cocos2d app. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The storyboard to me is simply a collection of images and text boxes, with segues between them. Currently, I plan on creating completely different storyboard files for each planned dialog with completely separate NPCs. when the two "rects"(centered around player and NPC) touch, I need to instantiate the storyboard or the view controller for the particular storyboard. I realize that this may not be the most efficient or even possible outcome, so any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "load a storyboard?" A storyboard is a collection of "scenes", which represent the views and controls for a view controller.

Most iOS apps only use 1 storyboard, which can contain dozens of view controllers. If you've used XIB files, a storyboard is like a collection of XIB files.

You don't load a storyboard in response to a user action. Instead, you instantiate a view controller from an already-active storyboard.

Take a look at the UIStoryboard method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:. You pass it a string identifier and it creates a view controller labeled with that id and gives it back to you. You can then present that view controller modally, push it onto a navigation controller stack, or a variety of other things.

What is it you are trying to accomplish in user-interface terms? Are you trying to display a new screen of some kind?

It's probably better to explain what you are trying to do with the user interface and then we can give you advice as to how to accomplish it.

Comment: the storyboard to me is simply a collection of images and text boxes, with segues between them. currently, i plan on creating completely different storyboard files for each planned dialog with completely separate NPCs. when the two "rects"(centered around player and NPC) touch, i need to instantiate the storyboard or the view controller for the particular storyboard.